# "granular level" for image

Tags: american-english

I'm writing a scientific paper about image processing. Before I study the image whose resolution is 30, and now I want to study image whose resolution is 500. I want to write this sentence "Now I study the image at a more granular level". Is it easy to follow by reviewer?

I want to search "granular" in Google scholar to find some paper use this word, but I only find "granular" is usually used for "feature", eg, "a more granular feature". I'm not sure it can be used for describing the image resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite being a non-specialist on image processing, I can tell you that 'granular' is used in everyday English to mean a pixellated image. So in this context, it would be an appropriate word :) Although it might be clearer to write 'now, I will study a lower-resolution image'

Just to clarify, are you referring to two separate images, or the same image at different resolutions?

Comment: Thanks! I'm studying the satellite imagery of one state in the US. So before I use a low-resolution image, now I use a higher-resolution image. (Sorry, I wrote it in reverse. I change the post to before 30 and now 500)

Comment: Sounds interesting! Without knowing the technical background to this, I can't be fully confident this is the best way of wording what you want to say, but higher-resolution / lower-resolution is certainly grammatically correct :)

Comment: It could be worth posting on stackoverflow with the image-processing tag if you want a more technical answer?

Comment: Ok, thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 2):

Granularity is, in effect,  how many 'grains' any data can be divided into. Your 500px image has a higher granularity than your 30px image.

However, granularity is more used for data representation than image resolution.

I would just use 'higher resolution' which is a term more familiar to most people. You can even specify what pixel count you have in each image. People will these days mainly be familiar with that used as a term of granularity/resolution in photographs.

Comment: Thanks, I also think it's better